# Get related posts by tags

Tags: mysql, tags, posts, relation

Hi I'm very bad at writing mysql queries (I'm working on it).

Could you guys help me with this one?

I have a table of tags:

```
id | tag
--------------------------------
1  | css
2  | c++
3  | perl
4  | sql
5  | pyhton
```

Another table of PostsA_tags:

```
id | postID | tag
--------------------------------
1  | 1      | 1
2  | 1      | 2
3  | 2      | 1
4  | 2      | 3
5  | 3      | 3
```

Another table of PostsB_tags:

```
id | postID | tag
--------------------------------
1  | 1      | 2
2  | 2      | 3
3  | 2      | 1
4  | 3      | 4
5  | 3      | 5
```

Another table of PostA:

```
postID | info
--------------------------------
1      | this
2      | is
2      | infor
3      | mation
4      | lol
```

Another table of PostB:

```
postID | info
--------------------------------
1      | more
2      | infor
3      | mation
4      | please
5      | hahaha
```

So now, the challenge is to order B posts from the A posts.

This means that if Peter is the owner of A posts, we need to get all his tags from all his posts. In this case it would be:

```
css, c++, perl
```

While, Sam is the owner of B posts. Now we need to order Sam's posts (B posts), by the amount of coincidences between Peter's tags (A tags) and the tags from each Sam's post.

In this case it would be:

B Posts ordered by coincided factor DESC

```
postID | info
--------------------------------
2      | infor 
1      | more
3      | mation
4      | please
5      | hahaha
```

I'm really stuck. I know how to get Sam's tags. But not how to measure the coincidence factor between Sam's tags and the tags from each Peter's post.

Sorry for my english :S

Thanks in advance

Here's a fiddle... sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8450c/3

Comment: Here you go --> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8450c/3

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really understand the logic - also 'a','b','sam','peter' - it's a bit confusing. And also... note that the surrogate id columns in your link tables are all redundant because you have a natural PK. Finally, the data set provided here differs from that in the fiddle (a typing error I suspsect).

Comment: So, if I understand correctly... A2 and B2 are "closest" because they are tagged identically. But is A1 more similar to B2 or B1, and why?

Comment: No. It's hard to explain. The reason why B2 is at the top is because the tags of B2 have more coincidences with Sam's tags which are css, c++, perl. Sam's tags are all the tags from all A posts and are unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have resolved the problem.

Here is the query

```
SELECT *, SUM(`PostsA_tags`.`tag` = `PostsB_tags`.`tag`) as rel FROM `PostsB_tags`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `PostsA_tags` `PostsA_tags` ON(`PostsA_tags`.`tag` = `PostsB_tags`.`tag`)
GROUP BY `PostsB_tags`.`postID`
ORDER BY rel DESC
```